# Mongoose unable to create new document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a article model defined as:

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({

    type: String
    ,title: String
    ,content: String

    ,comments: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId
        ,ref: 'Comment'
    }]

    ,replies: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId
        ,ref: 'Reply'
    }]


    ,feedbacks: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId
        ,ref: 'Feedback'
    }]

    ,meta: {
        tags: [String] //anything
        ,apps: [{
            store: String //app store, google play, amazon app store
            ,storeId: String
        }]
        ,category: String
    }


    //normal, deleted, banned
    , status: String
    ,statusMeta: {
        createdBy: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId
            ,ref: 'User'
        }
        ,createdDate: Date
        , updatedBy: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId
            ,ref: 'User'
        }
        ,updatedDate: Date

        ,deletedBy: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
        ,deletedDate: Date

        ,undeletedBy: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
        ,undeletedDate: Date

        ,bannedBy: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
        ,bannedDate: Date
        ,unbannedBy: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }

        ,unbannedDate: Date
    }
})
```

I have the following code to create a new article and save it.

```
var newArticle = new Article()
newArticle.status = helper.constant.articleTypes.other
newArticle.type = req.body.type
newArticle.category = req.body.category
newArticle.title = req.body.title
newArticle.content = req.body.content
newArticle.meta = req.body.meta
newArticle.statusMeta.createdBy = req.user
newArticle.statusMeta.createdDate = new Date
newArticle.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        return next(err)
}
```

My pre save hook (helper function)

```
exports.batchValidationWrapper = function(schema, module, fieldPaths) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldPaths.length; i++) {
        var fieldPath = fieldPaths[i]
        ;(function(fieldPath) {
            schema.pre('save', true, function(next, done) {
                var self = this

                var validationFunction = exports.validation[module][fieldPath]
                var msg = validationFunction(self[fieldPath])
                if (msg) {
                    self.invalidate(fieldPath, msg)
                    done(msg)
                }
                else {
                    done()
                }

            })
        })(fieldPath)
    }
}
```

and in my model i call helper

```
helper.batchValidationWrapper(ArticleSchema, 'article', [
    'type'
    ,'title'
    ,'content'
    ,'comments'
    ,'replies'
    ,'feedbacks'
    ,'meta.tags'
    ,'meta.apps'
    ,'meta.category'
    ,'status'
    ,'statusMeta.createdBy'
    ,'statusMeta.createdDate'
    ,'statusMeta.deletedBy'
    ,'statusMeta.deletedDate'
    ,'statusMeta.undeletedBy'
    ,'statusMeta.undeletedDate'
    ,'statusMeta.bannedBy'
    ,'statusMeta.bannedDate'
    ,'statusMeta.unbannedBy'
    ,'statusMeta.unbannedDate'


])
```

helper.validation is defined as following. It's basically bunches of functions that receive input and return error message if any. If no error just return `''`

```
exports.article = {

    type: function(input) {
        if (!input)
            return 'type is requried'
        return passIfAmongTypes('Article', input, constant.articleTypes)
    }

    ,'statusMeta.createdDate': function(input) {
        if (!input)
            return 'created date is required'
        return ''
    }
}
```

I got error saying that `created date is required` when I try to create a new article.

I have tried `newArticle.markModified('statusMeta')` and newArticle.markModified(`statusMeta.createdDate`), both not working. I dont think it's necessary to mark it modified, since it's `nested object` type, not `mixed` type (from mongoose doc)

I also tried setting `newArticle.statusMeta = {}`, not working either.

When I set the break point, newArticle.statusMeta.createdDate is undefined

The reason I dont want to use default value for createdDate is that, setting default seems to happen before running pre('save') hook, which makes my validation code always fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my own bug. Inside `helper.js` I used `helper.funcName()` instead of `exports.funcName()`. it's so hard to debug in javascript even with webstorm IDE.